# Toilet paper orientation

Tags: usability, user-behavior, physical

[In surveys of American consumers and of bath and kitchen specialists, 60–70% of respondents prefer over](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toilet_paper_orientation).

What are the primary experience factors that lead a majority of users to choose *over*?

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a discussion stated in the "question". UX.SE doesn't allow discussions or opinion based questions. Edit the question to fit the form of the community. See the help section at the top of the page. 

Comment: In all honesty, this isn't an opinion based question. It is searching for an objective answer to an everyday problem in the context of user experience.  If you consider it subjective, then looking at the help section, this question has almsot all the characteristics of a "great subjective question".  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Comment: I think this is quite a nice question about physical ergonomics.   The 'Over Setting' of the control somehow feels right to me as well - so the question is "why is this the preferred orientation of the control ?".   It may have something to do with our general perception of 'standards' for physical controls - ie to make something move 'up' you push the associated control 'up'.

Comment: Thx @kwahn for finding a way to get this important question on UX.SE! The stuffy academic factor here just went down 8.33%.

Comment: @plainclothes I was surprised to find it closed for almost 2 years

Comment: Seriously, 4 close votes again? What's wrong with you guys!? This site has a rather poor reputation with many UXers. This stuffiness is why.

Comment: @plainclothes It's not about 'stuffiness' it's about having answerable questions. This is a discussion topic, not an answerable question.

Comment: @JonW, can't we have a little UX humor? I know it's hard to draw the line, but this is stimulating me to think about my work in a more pleasurable fashion.

Comment: @MaaikevanReekum Fun questions would be fine, provided you can structure it in a format that fits this site. This question is too broad for that. It's not the subject matter that is the problem, it is the format of the question itself.

Comment: @JonW given the most recent edit I don't see how it is too broad. "Which usability factors bring better user experience of the "over" choice?" is perfectly answerable, as you can see by Alexey  and mc01's answers.

Comment: @JonW Can you please explain how this question is too broad?

Comment: @ZachSaucier It is asking for peoples opinions on some usability factors. It is not precise, it is not asking for *the* answer to a problem. There is no solution to this question, just discussion. Questions should be focused "I have X problem, I have tried Y solution to solve it but it has not worked, what should I be doing". Not "Tell me some usability factors".

Comment: @JonW - There is no precise *the* solution to *any* design problem. There are always multiple options for discussion. If that weren't the case every thread would have a single "correct" answer and everything ever designed by man would eventually converge on the same "correct" result. That doesn't happen, because UX questions are *all* inherently imprecise & subjective. This is built right into the name - "experience." The entire field revolves around analyzing & responding to subjective opinions.

Comment: @mc01 Whether there is an *actual* solution is not so much the issue though. It's around asking questions in a way that can solicit a theoretical correct answer. "Tell me some things about..." is not a question that could ever have a correct answer, but "How can I get x to work" is. See the link that Kwahn referenced in an earlier comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Answer (score 8):

Soviet ergonomic school has proof for my theses. I mean the toilet paper issue was not the main point of the field. Partly because the toilet paper itself was a scarce product, as I remember from those times. I'm not joking.
[image]

Comment: Another point to add in regards to "More far from the wall" is keeping both the wall and people's hands cleaner

Comment: *Further from the wall

Answer (score 7):

The [original patent application from 1891](http://www.businessinsider.com/patent-shows-right-way-to-hang-toilet-paper-2015-3) clearly shows "over" as the preferred orientation:
[image: 1891 toilet paper patent images]

Pros:

- fewer sheets used (less waste)
- easier to find the starting point
- tears effectively with a single hand, whereas "under" requires 2 hands or else you unravel even more paper and have to [put your cell phone away](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/survey-75-percent-of-americans-admit-to-using-phone-while-in-bathroom/) (eew).
- it's closer and requires no contact with a potentially filthy wall.
- "Over" also helps to prevent the *extremely likely* & *ever-present danger* of being attacked by a spider hanging out on the back of the roll:

[image: There IS a spider on your toilet paper!]

HOWEVER! These benefits apply primarily to People Without Cats.

The "over" orientation is notoriously inconvenient for cat owners, because it allows for easy & continuous unraveling with a single "thwap".

[image: cat unrolls toilet paper]

Most feline users also prefer the "over" for this highly entertaining reason, though some have learned to use it more properly than most:
http://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-2597369/Hilarious-video-shows-cat-unraveling-entire-roll-toilet-paper-dutifully-rolling-again.html

Comment: I wonder if the inventor actually used one square at a time...

Comment: That cat does make the paper more fluffy and airy. Doesn't everyone want that? (According to the commercials)

Comment: I don't see how the patent info actually backs up most of the claims made in the bullet points. In fact, the patent (and most advantages) are actually referring to the fact that the toilet paper is *perforated* not that it's hanging in a specific direction.

Comment: @DA01 The patent is just confirmation of the *right* direction. The most important piece of evidence here is obviously the spider exhibit.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the great reasons that Alexey provides, **the ability for users to *see* where the current piece to take is** helps as well. If a dispenser uses the "under" orientation, that piece may be facing the wall which makes it impossible for people to visually tell which way they should turn it (if it's not hanging down), causing an extra turn sometimes.